# Python - how to create multiple attribute by list

Tags: python, python-2.7

how can i create multiple attribute by list, for example:

my code:

```
class test():
    def __init__(self, name):
       pass...
    def test2(self, lista):
```

but in this method i create one object (the final element of my list.
How can i create multiple self.ris to generate multiple object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) to set the attribute's name to a variable:

```
class pkg():
    def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name
            lista_ = self.dai_lista(lista)
            print lista_
            for i in lista_:
                    i = i.rstrip()
                    setattr(self, 'ris'+i, riso(i))
    def dai_lista(self, lista):
            print "sono in dai lista"
            return lista

class riso():
        def __init__(self, nome):
                self.nome = nome
        def print_nome(self):
                print self.nome

lista = ['a', 'b', 'c' ]
pippo = pkg('pippo')
pippo.risa.print_nome()
pippo.risb.print_nome()
pippo.risc.print_nome()
```

---

Output:

```
sono in dai lista
['a', 'b', 'c']
a
b
c
```

---

However, although this works, I would consider dynamic creating of instance attributes bad practice. Instead, you should use a dict to store these classes:

```
class pkg():
    def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name
            lista_ = self.dai_lista(lista)
            print lista_
            self.ris = {}
            for i in lista_:
                    i = i.rstrip()
                    self.ris[i] = riso(i)
    def dai_lista(self, lista):
            print "sono in dai lista"
            return lista

class riso():
        def __init__(self, nome):
                self.nome = nome
        def print_nome(self):
                print self.nome

lista = ['a', 'b', 'c' ]
pippo = pkg('pippo')
pippo.ris['a'].print_nome()
pippo.ris['b'].print_nome()
pippo.ris['c'].print_nome()
```

And the output is the same as if you had used attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method like so:

```
def make_attrs(self, *lista):
    for l in lista:
        setattr(self, l, None)
```

Where `None` will initialize the values for you. If you want to create key-value pairs, you can create a dictionary:

```
myattrs = {'k': 'v',...}

def make_attrs(self, *args, **kwargs):
    for l in args:
        setattr(self, l, None)
    for k,v in kwargs.items():
        setattr(self, k, v)
```

It's generally better practice to do this in the `__init__` method (I think it's a PEP standard, SO can keep me honest here), but that's a kind of hacky way to do it